# Collection or documents for multiple projects?

Tags: mongodb

I want to manage multiple projects data in mongoDB. Each project contains multiple users from multiple departments with multiple role assigned to them. plus certain task is assigned to each user. Now I am confused about schema, not able to decide which entity should be kept as collection & which one as document ?  What is the best efficient way to store ?
should I keep all under single collection as embedded documents or in separate collection ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you are using mongodb you should know why are you using it. MongoDB is not about normalize stuff. If you are able to create data structure is de-normalize way then and only then go for MongoDB.

I think you should maintain one single document containing all the mentioned things above. But the scenario which you have mentioned above is good for relational database. you need only 3 entities in relational database and your problem is solved.

Still if you want to go for mongodb you can go with one collection only. which contains project details number of users working there and their roles and department.